# how can utilize dev.copy or svalue in ggraphics?

Tags: r, gwidgets

i have a gui with a area ggraphics and i would want create a subwindow with the graphic active in the area graphic, but dev.copy and svalue not work

```
options(guiToolkit = "RGtk2")
win<- gwindow ("window", width=1350,height=680,parent=c(1,1))
buttongraph<-gbutton("Click for enlarge graph",cont=win)
wingraphic<- ggraphics(cont=win)
hist(rnorm(100))
addHandlerChanged(buttongraph,handler=function(h,...){
subwin<- gwindow("subwin")
subwingraph<-ggraphics(cont=subwin)
svalue(wingraphic)
})
```

or

```
dev.copy(wingraphic)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call `svalue(wingraphic) <- "filename.png"` tries to produce a graphic using some Gtk calls. It is fragile and if the comment in the file is still accurate, needs the device to be uncovered. Might work for you, but might not.

The ggraphics widget is just a frontend for `cairoDevice` which opens a new graphics device. If it was the current device, the call would be `dev.copy()`, not `dev.copy(wingraphic)` as `dev.copy` knows nothing about `gWidgets` objects. If you want to get the device for a given `ggraphics` object you can grab it with: `getToolkitWidget(g)$getData(".devnum")`, but you'll need to load `RGtk2` first.

If you just want to make a given `ggraphics` instance the current device, you can do so with `visible(subwingraph) <- TRUE`.

Comment: i want to enlarge the active graph in `wingraph` in a subwindow `subwingraph` but i dont want to utilize `subwingraph <- ggraphics(cont=subwin) ; hist(rnorm(100))` because the idea is update the graph in `wingraphic` and the code used, it can to update this graph on `subwingraph` without changing the code

Comment: You might want to write the current graphic to an image file and display through `gimage` in that case.